# CoAP support for twitter heron

Tags: apache-storm, iot, coap, heron

I'm working on IoT project where I receive datastream in CoAP protocol.
I want to process the data in Heron by doing some transformations on top of it.
Is it possible to integrate CoAP protocol objects to heron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not very important from the CoAP endpoint's view where do you put the received data.

Use this link as a initial point:
http://coap.technology/impls.html

There you can find brief descriptions for implementations for several languages/platforms.

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with Twitter Heron and don't know which language is best for implementing a Heron data provider.

If such language is Java or Heron is language-agnostic (say, has a REST API as a primary interface) - I'd consider the https://eclipse.org/californium/ as a very mature implementation. That way (sure in 5000ft view as I don't know the details) you could write an app which uses Californium and CoapHandlers might push data to Heron.